# SQL 2005 Logshipping

Tags: sql-server

I have sql 2005 logshipping. Is it possible to backup current state this database, when is database restoring ? 
Because i need database from previous day for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no possible to backup database in warm-stanby mode.

You can backup your primary database with COPY_ONLY option (BACKUP DATABASE database_name TO  … WITH COPY_ONLY …). It preserves the existing log archive point and, therefore, does not affect the sequencing of log shipping transaction logs backups. 
Then restore this backup at specified point of time using SQL Server Management studio or sql script using 'RESTORE DATABASE ... WITH STOPAT ...' command.